Jensen's inequality in the proof of the Information inequality theorem
Elements of Information Theory states that for two probability mass functions: $$p(x), q(x), x \in \mathcal{X} \ ,$$ and $$A = \{x: p(x) > 0 \}$$
$$
\sum_{x\in A} p(x) \log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} 
\leq 
\log \sum_{x\in A} p(x) \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} \ ,
$$
due to Jensen's inequality:
$$
E\ f(X) \leq f(E\ X)
$$
when $f$ is concave (see this question for a screenshot with context). To me, this seems like a situation where $f = \log \ $ and $$g(x) = q(x)/p(x)$$ and that Jensen's inequality has been extended to the case:
$$
E\ f(g(X)) \leq f(E\ g(X)) \ ,
$$
where $f$ is concave. Is my interpretation correct? If so, why can Jensen's inequality be extended in this way?

In Jensen's inequality, take $X$ to be  a random variable taking the value $\frac {g(x)} {p(x)}$ with probabilty $p(x)$ .

$g(X)$ is in itself a random variable. If you want, we could call it $Y:=g(X)$. Then what you're using is just standard Jensen's, there's no extension going on, you're just using
$$\mathbb Ef(Y)\leq f\left(\mathbb EY\right)$$

It is possible to compute the expected values of $q(X)/p(X)$ and $\log q(X)/p(X)$ as in @Andrades answer to this question because of the Law Of The Unconscious Statistician, or LOTUS for short. LOTUS becomes kind of a pain to work with unless you assume that $q(x)/p(x)$ is injective (1-to-1), so that for $x_1, x_2 \in A,$
$$
x_1 \neq x_2 \implies q(x_1)/p(x_1) \neq q(x_2)/p(x_2).
$$
This assumption makes sense because all work you have to put into relaxing it is undone once you take the sum of the expected value. See Wikipedia for details.
So, assuming for ease of exposition that $q(x)/p(x)$ is injective, let
$$
B = \{ q(x)/p(x) : x \in A \}
$$
and $Y$ be the random variable that, for each $x \in A$ takes the value $q(x)/p(x)$ with probability $p(x)$, so that the probability mass function $p'$ of $Y$ is
$$
p'(q(x)/p(x)) = p(x), x \in A.
$$
Then,
$$
\sum_{x \in A} p(x) \log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}
=
\sum_{y \in B} p'(y) \log y
=
E\ \log Y
$$
because $p(x) = p'(q(x)/p(x)) = p'(y)$ by definition and $q(x)/p(x) = y$ by definition.
For similar reasons we can write
$$
\log \sum_{x \in A} p(x) \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}
=
\log \sum_{y \in B} p'(y) y
=
\log E\ Y
$$
